# Загрузка пути картики на сервер, полученной от клиента Windows Phone

Tags: python, django, windows-phone-7

Пишу REST API для блога на Windows Phone. Использую фреймворк Django. В попытке добавления статьи столкнулся с такой проблемой - не понимаю как сохранить в бд путь до картинки и саму картинку на сервере, которую мне прислал пользователь моего приложения на WPhone.
Если посчу статью со своего сайта, то все путем(но там я делаю через формы),
а тут что-то не получается.
Если кто знает, помогите пожалуйста.

Это models.py

```
class Entry(models.Model):
def get_image_path(self, filename):
    position = filename.rindex(".")
    name = filename[:position]
    last = filename[position:]
    path = "html/"+str(translit.slugify(name))+last
    return path
title = models.CharField(max_length=20, unique=True)
tags = models.CharField(max_length=20)
content = models.TextField(max_length=15000, help_text="To add picture in the text write #picture (in spaces) where you want to paste picture")
date = models.DateTimeField()
author = models.ForeignKey(User)
image1 = models.ImageField(upload_to=get_image_path, blank=True)
image2 = models.ImageField(upload_to=get_image_path, blank=True)
image3 = models.ImageField(upload_to=get_image_path, blank=True)

class Meta:
    db_table = 'Entry'
    ordering = ('-date',)
```

это views.py

```
 if request.method == 'POST':

    ruAuthor = int(request.META['HTTP_RUAUTHOR'])
    if ruAuthor == 0:
        n = request.META['HTTP_AUTHOR']
        name = translit.detranslify(n)
    else:
        name = request.META['HTTP_AUTHOR']

    try:
        acc = User.objects.get(username=name)
    except:
        return HttpResponse(json.dumps("Do not exist"), content_type='application/json')

    if acc.is_active != 1:
        data = json.dumps('Sorry, but You are not logged in.')
        return HttpResponse(data, content_type='application/json')
    else:
        date = datetime.datetime.now()
        ruTitle = int(request.META['HTTP_RUTITLE'])
        ruTags = int(request.META['HTTP_RUTAGS'])
        ruContent = int(request.META['HTTP_RUCONTENT'])

        user = auth.authenticate(username=name, password=request.META['HTTP_PASSWORD'])
        if user.password != acc.password:
            return HttpResponse(json.dumps('Error'), content_type='application/json')

        if ruTitle == 0:
            t = request.META['HTTP_TITLE']
            title = translit.detranslify(t)
        else:
            title = request.META['HTTP_TITLE']

        if ruTags == 0:
            tg = request.META['HTTP_TAGS']
            tags = translit.detranslify(tg)
        else:
            tags = request.META['HTTP_TAGS']

        if ruContent == 0:
            c = request.META['HTTP_CONTENT']
            content = translit.detranslify(c)
        else:
            content = request.META['HTTP_CONTENT']

        entry = Entry.objects.create(title=title, tags=tags, content=content, date=date, author=acc)
    return HttpResponse(json.dumps('Added'), content_type='application/json')
```

P.S. это мой очень тестовый проект, недавно начал разбираться, поэтому немного быдлокод

Answer (score 1):

У вас есть модель Entry. В ней 3 поля ImageField. Когда вы загружаете картинку, она сохраняется по указанному пути. Получить путь к изображению Вы можете так:

```
my_entry = Entry.objects.get(title="foo")
image_path = my_entry.image1.path
image_url = my_entry.image1.url
```

image_path - это путь к файлу картинки на диске (напимер /home/user/static/image1.jpg)
image_url - это путь в виде ссылки (напимер /static/image1.jpg)

Для того чтобы с помощью формы загрузить картинку, используйте django.forms.
Примеры есть здесь https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/http/file-uploads/